# How do I create objects with computed property names?

Tags: javascript, angular, object

Im trying to build an object out of checkbox selections from different components.

I have a basic idea of how to do it, but I'm stuck on building out the object. I am getting "undefined" when trying to add to an object in Angular.

My goal is to have an object like this, which builds after each checkbox is checked in the button menu:

```json
{
  "first":{
     "0" : "one",
     "1" : "two",
  },
  "second":{
     "0": "five",
     "1": "six",
     "2": "seven",
   },
   "third":{
     "0": "eight",
     "1": "nine",
    }
  }
}
```

Right now Im getting something like this, and the values are overwritten, and not adding like I want them to:

```json
{ "first": { "1": "two" }, "second": { "1": "six" } }
```

Im not sure what I am missing.

The button handler code is as below:

```js
  buttonHandler(event: any) {
    console.log('event', event);

    let pillName = event.pillName;
    let filterName = event.filterValue;
    let idx = event.index;

    this.testObj[pillName] = {  [idx]: filterName };

    console.log('testObj', this.testObj);
  }
```

The stackblitz is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/kingsbury-angular-w-material-fyzxhd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I have `@Inputs` and `@Outputs` sending and receiving the data OK, but Im lost on the object creation logic. Any help is appreciated!

*EDIT*

Here is just plain javscript

```js
let aaa = [
  { id: 1, filterName: 'one', checked: false },
  { id: 2, filterName: 'two', checked: false },
  { id: 3, filterName: 'three', checked: false },
];

let bbb = [
  { id: 1, filterName: 'five', checked: false },
  { id: 2, filterName: 'six', checked: false },
  { id: 3, filterName: 'seven', checked: false },
];

let ccc = [
  { id: 1, filterName: 'eight', checked: false },
  { id: 2, filterName: 'nine', checked: false },
  { id: 3, filterName: 'ten', checked: false },
];

let items = [
  { id: 1, pillName: 'first', filterValues: aaa },
  { id: 2, pillName: 'second', filterValues: bbb },
  { id: 3, pillName: 'third', filterValues: ccc },
];

let testObject = {}

function buttonHandler(event) {
  console.log('event', event);

  let pillName = event.pillName;
  let filterName = event.filterValue;
  let idx = event.index;

  testObject[pillName] = { [idx]: filterName };

  console.log('testObj', testObject);
}

buttonHandler({pillName: "first", filterValue: "one", index: 0, checked: true})
buttonHandler({pillName: "first", filterValue: "two", index: 1, checked: true})
buttonHandler({pillName: "second", filterValue: "six", index: 1, checked: true})
buttonHandler({pillName: "second", filterValue: "seven", index: 2, checked: true})
```

Comment: *"My goal is to have an object like this"*: that seems a wrong target. "first", "second", "three"... Have you considered arrays?

Comment: I have, but that is not the use case for this scenario. The list of filters and other items is expected to grow, so ideally I want to look up the properties quickly, because they will always be added and removed from this main object list

Comment: I don't follow links. Is it not possible to limit this question to just the data structure? I don't  see any reason why Angular needs to play a role in this question, not even buttons. Please provide input and expected output in a runnable script.

Comment: ok added plain javascript. expected input and output are in the question and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do, but you could try modifying the `buttonHandler` function line to instead look like this:

```
this.testObj[pillName] = { ...this.testObj[pillName], [idx]: filterName };
```

The spread syntax (three dots) basically copies the existing array, then adds the new `idx` instead of replacing the existing array with just the new `idx`.

And thank you for providing a stackblitz! I find it much easier to help if I can run the code and try out possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks! I am basically going to make an aggregate list of all of the chosen filters selected in the drops downs where new ones can be added/removed

Comment: Did the above change work for you?

Comment: It did what I wanted it to do. Thanks for the fix and the explanation!